# After Rails Upgrade to 5.2 and ruby to 2.5.7 getting undefined method `prepend' for #<HTTP::Client error in my rails project

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rubygems, ruby-on-rails-5.2

After rails upgrade to version 5.2 and ruby to 2.5.7 I am getting below error in my rails project
I have upgraded `faraday` gem as well but not able to solve this.
Any help is appriciable.

```
NoMethodError: undefined method `prepend' for #<HTTP::Client:0x00007ff4dc21a470> Did you mean? present?
```

Comment: Are you using this gem?  https://www.rubydoc.info/gems/httpclient/2.1.5.2/HTTPClient  There is no 'prepend' method on that class in the latest version.

Comment: Currently using httpclient (~> 2.7) gem in my project

Answer (score 0):

https://www.rubydoc.info/gems/httpclient/2.7.1#features

Select the "Methods" link in the top left

Search for 'prepend'

There is no such method.  There is a literal bug wherever this line is being called.  You haven't pasted the stack trace, but below this error, there is probably a line about which file and what line in that file is responsible for this error.  You should change the code in that file (if it's code you authored) or you should stop using whatever library is causing this line to be called.